# Good references for learning Mixing?

Tags: mixing, references, online, learning

I am learning how to mix and there is a lot to it.

What are some good online references or places I can learn how to mix?

When I say learning how to mix, I don't mean so much the beginning technical side of it. I am more talking about the artistic.

I wonder if such a place exists or if you sort of learn as you do it and create your own "style". I'd love to hear your opinions on the matter.

Comment: Wow, that's weird I was thinking of asking this question today.

Comment: Are you asking about mixing music, or sound for picture? They're both quite different at times. The post world is much more standardized and the music world could stand to be more standardized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you find something Ryan, please let me know! I searched for the reference for the elusive "perfect mix" for years. :)

However I WILL recommend the Gearslutz Post-Pro forum - there are some very experienced mixers on there who, if approached politely, are quite willing to give advice.

I found in the end, just doing it was the best way. Along with being able to sit in with some far more experienced mixers. If you can wrangle the chance to do so, DO IT - just watching a seasoned mixer work will improve your own work immensely!

As well, I still listen, very closely in fact, to other films and TV shows, to hear what I like and what I don't like about other mixes. I try and learn something new on every mix I do, and usually do.

Finally, one of the MOST important lessons I learned, was to SERVE THE PROJECT ABOVE ALL. Put aside your personal tastes, opinions and theories and mix the project the way it wants/needs to mixed, NOT the way you think it should be mixed. I spent a great deal of wasted time and effort early on in my career trying to make things sound the way I THOUGHT they should be, instead of simply making them sound GOOD (or at least as good as they could be). Good varies from project to project - what sounds good for one, will sound like crap on another (listen to "Traffic" next to "The Matrix" next to "No Country for Old Men").

Once you make that "Zen" step of taking yourself out of the equation, oddly enough finding your own voice becomes easy.

Comment: Wow. Thanks Sonsey. Answer of the week right there.

Comment: And if you know any mixers in LA who would let me sit in with them, let me know :)

Comment: You're welcome! It's funny... I used to HATE mixing when I started editing. It took me a long time to get comfortable with it. Fortunately, through editing and sound design I was able to sit with other mixers and get a better feel for it. 

Comment: @Sonsey I'm the complete opposite I find mixing really fun but hate editing, I don't know why I have a hard time dealing with it.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest "Mixing with your mind" by Michael Paul Stavrou.
It made me rethink on loads of recording and mixing issues.
Very interesting, clear and entertaining reading.

Comment: Sweet gotta check that out

Answer (score 0):

*Mixing audio* by Roey Izhaki is worth a read. It's all about mixing music but the principles are applicable for Film and TV.

Answer (score 0):

Check this post on gearslutz ;)
http://www.gearslutz.com/board/post-production-forum/229741-standard-mixing-levels-movie-theater-dvd-broadcast-tv-commercials-etc.html